# how to use less & bootstrap in angular 6 project?

Tags: css, angular, bootstrap-4, less

I have edit the angular.json styleext for using less

```
"schematics": {
    "@schematics/angular:component": {
      "prefix": "app",
      "styleext": "less"
    },
    "@schematics/angular:directive": {
      "prefix": "app"
    }
  }
```

I create a component and test the less it works. But now i want to mix the component css/less with the bootgstrap classes.

For example I want all button in my component to have .mx-1

I type in my less:

```
.btnmx-1{
   .btn();
   .mx-1();
}
```

but it failed. I tried to import :

```
 @import "../../../../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";

.btnmx-1{
   .btn();
   .mx-1();
}
```

this one also failed to compile with error : **.btn is undefined**

How to fix this ? I want all buttons in my component to have margin left and right 1px inherited from bootstrap

Answer (score 0):

For **Bootsrap**:

```
npm install bootsrap --save
```

in `angular.json`:

```
  "styles": [
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css",
              "src/styles.scss"
            ],
```

For **less**:

add `less` file type instead  `css` (by default)

```
comp.component.less
```

in `angular.json`.

Set the property `defaults.styleExt` to `less`.

Comment: and use ngx-bootstrap on top of it 
`npm install ngx-bootstrap --save`

Comment: i have done that. also i use ngx-bootstrap. the problem only i cannot mix the bootstrap class into my component class.

Comment: do you have jquery and popper.js install check in package.json?

Comment: @Akj, in bootstrap 5, you **not** use jquery nor popper, else in angular.json-->scripts add `"node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" `

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I use bootstrap in my project

1. Download bootstrap **Source files** from link: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/download/
2. create styles folders in your project copy **scss folder** from resource to it and rename it to bootstrap to more clearly
3. create your own mixin and import it bootstrap.scss file(below all of the existing imports)
4. import bootstrap.scss to style.scss(or in angular.json)

In my case, I just want to use bootstrap utils classes like padding, margin,heading...so I just keep these files in my boostrap scss folder
[image]

If you need all just keep all or remove some modules that need bootstrap js to run like carousel....